# (Spring) Unsatisfied Dependency Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I'm facing the issue with spring MVC and Hibernate. The problem is, it gives me `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException`.

Here is the error:

```
18-Apr-2022 00:36:22.172 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in file [D:\Coding\Java\Spring_Framework\zzz\target\zzz\WEB-INF\classes\com\bai\controller\CustomerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\Coding\Java\Spring_Framework\zzz\target\zzz\WEB-INF\classes\com\bai\dao\CustomerDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.bai.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1775)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\Coding\Java\Spring_Framework\zzz\target\zzz\WEB-INF\classes\com\bai\dao\CustomerDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.bai.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
        ... 61 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\Coding\Java\Spring_Framework\zzz\target\zzz\WEB-INF\classes\com\bai\dao\CustomerDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.bai.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
        ... 75 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.bai.config.HibernateConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
        ... 88 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
        ... 102 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:145)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:124)
        at com.bai.config.HibernateConfig.getSessionFactory(HibernateConfig.java:30)
        at com.bai.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89956522.CGLIB$getSessionFactory$2(<generated>)
        at com.bai.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89956522$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6324619c.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
        at com.bai.config.HibernateConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$89956522.getSessionFactory(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 103 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
        ... 118 more
18-Apr-2022 00:36:22.187 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
18-Apr-2022 00:36:22.276 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2022-04-18 12:36:22,315] Artifact zzz:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.406 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\Coding\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.78\webapps\manager]
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.480 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup Initializing Jasper for context [Tomcat Manager Application]
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.496 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/jsp/].
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.496 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.524 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.<init> Parent class loader is: [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: manager
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@52f759d7
]
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.524 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.initClassPath Compilation classpath initialized: C:\Users\baistan.tashkuov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\tomcat\0c7cc667-c02e-4913-aa73-958d11878231\work\Catalina\localhost\manager;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/annotations-api.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/catalina-ant.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/catalina-ha.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/catalina-tribes.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/catalina.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/ecj-4.6.3.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/el-api.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/jasper-el.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/jasper.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/jaspic-api.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/jsp-api.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/servlet-api.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-api.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-de.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-ko.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-ru.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-i18n-zh-CN.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-jni.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-util.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar;/D:/Coding/Java/apache-tomcat-8.5.78/lib/websocket-api.jar;D:\Coding\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.78\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Coding\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.78\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.532 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init Scratch dir for the JSP engine is: [C:\Users\baistan.tashkuov\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\tomcat\0c7cc667-c02e-4913-aa73-958d11878231\work\Catalina\localhost\manager]
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.533 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init IMPORTANT: Do not modify the generated servlets
18-Apr-2022 00:36:26.539 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\Coding\Java\apache-tomcat-8.5.78\webapps\manager] has finished in [133] ms
```

**My hibernate config file:**

```
package com.bai.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.bai"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:db.properties"})
public class HibernateConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("com.bai.entity");
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**App Init Config**

```
package com.bai.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer 
      extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
  }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.bai.controller;

import com.bai.services.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    final
    CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    private String showCustomers(Model model) {
        return "views/index";
    }

}
```

**Service Implemenation**

```
package com.bai.services;

import com.bai.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.bai.entity.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    final CustomerDao customerDao;

    public CustomerServiceImpl(CustomerDao customerDao) {
        this.customerDao = customerDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> list() {
        List<Customer> list = customerDao.getCustomers();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**DAO implementation**

```
package com.bai.dao;

import com.bai.entity.Customer;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao{

    final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public CustomerDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        List<Customer> list = null;
        try {
            list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            Query<Customer> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Custom");
            list = query.getResultList();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Follow the stack trace to check the root cause. This is something to look at `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accorading to your error log, the root cause is
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`.

Just add the following dependency to pom.xml.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```